# How to set Countdown Screen As Home Screen Wallpaper in Android.?

Tags: android

In My application, I make one countdown Screen for remaining days (like Countdown the days till Christmas) and now i want to make that screen as a Home Screen Wallpaper.

like this :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

IF you are displaying time in textbox than you can try this code also ..

```
class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
   public void run() {
       long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
       int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
       int minutes = seconds / 60;
       seconds     = seconds % 60;

       timeLabel.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
   }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want a static background image, you can do something like this and put in the onCreate of your main app:

```
// Set background image, rotatable
    View view = getWindow().getDecorView(); 
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
    if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == orientation) { 
        view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.yourimage); // Landscape
    } else { 
        view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.yourimgae); // Portrait
    }
```

Comment: i Will try this Thanks for your response and time for me @Lars